# Orbit Controls zoom issue

Tags: three.js

I am trying to get infinite zoom functionality,
While looking at the following three.js example: 
http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

While getting closer to the target vector, the zoom factor reduced and reduced until it barely worked, for an end user it looks like it is stuck. panning won't really work, and in order to zoom out user needs to use the mouse wheel for like ages.

Is there a way to get infinite zoom functionality?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you call infinite zoom : in OrbitControls [`mousewheel` event triggers the functions `dollyIn` or `dollyOut`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L217). You can see the zoom never stops, it divides or multiplies itself : `scale /= dollyScale` and `scale *= dollyScale`. The zoom _is_ infinite, the more you mousewheel, the more you will go closer the target, logarithmicly.

Comment: in this example, the camera is zooming. What you want is to move the camera and its target along the cam's view axis. You would have to change the orbit controls to your needs (replace the "zoom" function for example) to achieve this kind of effect that you are loocking for. 

The problem is that for a typical use case, orbit controls is correct in its behaviour because of getting closer to the target as Astrak said is expected. In this "open space/world" example, it does not make too much sense, though.

Comment: Astrak,GuyGood, In order to understand my question better, please try to enter the example link and  keep zooming in , you will see that you won't be able to reach the far end (without rotating).

Comment: @GuyGood for an "open space/world," is there a set of controls you'd recommend using instead?

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned it is zooming infinitely ( but it's zooming infinitely to the target at the center of the scene so it will never pass the target and thus never zoom beyond the center of the scene ), there's a couple changes you can make to the controls object in order to render the desired effect ( if I'm understanding you correctly ).

one small change you can make is change the target location from the center of the scene to the other end of the scene, given the the camera's far perameter is set to 1000 we can try setting the target's z position to -1000 in your init() function like so:

```
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1000);
```

here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gn7k0m4/

in that example you'll zoom past the scene and slow down when you get to -1000. Another approach might be to change the dollyIn and dollyOut methods so that rather than getting infinitely closer to the target what it does is change the camera's z index, this way when you zoom past the target the camera will still rotate around the center, you can do something like this

```
controls.dollyOut = function(){
    this.object.position.z -= 100;
}
controls.dollyIn = function(){
    this.object.position.z += 100;
}
```

here's a working fiddle for that example: http://jsfiddle.net/6gn7k0m4/1/

Comment: neither the mentioned js-fiddle, nor the code here works .. will remove this comment once fixed, and up-vote too ;-)

Comment: @argon hmm, you're right. it definitely worked 6 years ago when i made this post though. it looks like jsfiddle can't find the OrbitControls (despite being included as a resource)

Comment: Maybe try code-pen -or any other public code testing platform, where you can specify the library version?
-then update the link here?